# How can I list posts by author?

Tags: posts, menus, list-authors

How can I list posts as sub-items of authors? It should look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Author</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Post1</li>
            <li>Post2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have an array containing author data including `$author->ID`.
My function looks like this:

```
function add_custom_menu_items($items, $args) {

    $authors = get_users('role=author');

    return $items.$authors_str;    
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom_menu_items', 5, 2);
```

Where can I get a list of posts?

Comment: Can you explain the use case? Where are you trying to do this?

Comment: He simply wants to display lists of authors with a nested list of their posts. And he is adding authors to the navigation menu for a start. Check the second screenshot of this plugin, that's what he wants http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-posts-by-author/screenshots/

Comment: I looked at the code for that, but the comments are in Spanish. Otherwise that's exactly what I need. I am using it as a menu item in a Son-of-a-suckerfish dropdown. And I'm not a he.

Comment: hi @SinthiaV, you need this custom loop in a menu or a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simpler solution, if you want a total control over the code and don't want to use a query.

```
$authors = get_users('role=author');

if(isset($authors) && !empty($authors))
{
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($authors as $author)
    {
        $posts = get_posts(array('author'=>$author->ID));

        //if this author has posts, then include his name in the list otherwise don't
        if(isset($posts) && !empty($posts))
        {
            echo "<li>".$author->user_nicename."</li>";

            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($posts as $post)
            {
                echo "<li>".$post->post_title."</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

?>
```

You can also use this in your filter function.

Comment: I modified your solution a bit, but you put me back on the right track. The documentation for get_users() and get_posts() could be a little easier to find. Thankyou.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you need a list of posts by author in the menu? or in a custom page? Please make this clear in your question.

For the menu you can build a custom menu and style it with css to fit your needs.

For a page you can build a custom query:

```
<?php
// Get the authors from the database ordered by user nicename
global $wpdb;
$site_admin = ""; // enter Admin ID to exclude
$query = "SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE ID != '$site_admin' ORDER BY user_nicename";
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);

// Loop through each author
foreach($author_ids as $author) :
// Get user data
$curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);
// Get link to author page
$user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></li>
            <ul>
            <?php $author_query = new WP_Query( 'author='.$curauth->ID.'&posts_per_page=-1&' );
            while ( $author_query->have_posts() ) : $author_query->the_post(); ?>

                <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

you can put this in a custom page.
Also if you need to exclude the Administrator or any other user from the query, use the `$site_admin` var.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // the following is with Gravatar, Links to author pages ,and css classes-
<?php
    // Arguments to pass to get_users
    $args = array( 'orderby' => 'display_name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'who' => 'authors' );
    // Query for the users
    $authors = get_users( $args ); ?>

          <div id="authors-list"><p><strong>Authors: </strong>
    <?php
    // Loop through all the users, printing their names, with links to their section of the archives
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $authors ); ++$i ) {
      $author = $authors[$i];
      echo "<a href='#{$author->user_nicename}'>$author->display_name</a>";
      if ( $i < count( $authors ) - 1 ) {
        echo ' | ';
      }
    } ?>
          </p></div>

    <?php
    // Loop through all the users, and grab posts
    foreach ( $authors as $author ) { ?>
          <a name="<?php echo $author->user_nicename; ?>"></a>
          <div class="author-posts-container" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-posts-wrapper">
            <div class="author-avatar" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-avatar">
              <?php echo get_avatar( $author->ID, 96 ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="author-posts-list" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-posts">
              <h2><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $author->display_name; ?></a></h2>
      <?php
      // now a loop for each user post
      $args = array( 'author' => $author->ID, 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
      $posts = query_posts($args);
      // quasi-loop use get_template_part
      // if exists
      // get_template_part( 'loop', 'all-authors' ); // Pulls in loop-all-authors.php from theme
      if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <ul class="author-post-list" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-post-list">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // Print whatever we want for each post - for now the title and date ?>
              <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> &mdash; <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul><!-- #author-post-list -->
      <?php else: ?>
              <p>This author has no posts published</p>
      <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- #author-posts -->
          </div><!-- #author-posts-container -->
    <?php } // End looping  ?>
```

Comment: This may work, but it came later than Rutwick's, so I didn't get a chance to try it.